# Case-insensitive headers in SuperCSV writer?

Tags: java, case-insensitive, supercsv

Using CsvMapWriter if I add a header say, 'Region' and later write a row with key 'region' and value 'Northeast' it doesn't get added to the SuperCSV output. I'm assuming it doesn't find a valid column to put the value for 'region' in.

For this application I can't rename the headers, such as forcing lowercase. And the row key/value pairs, like 'region' and 'northeast' could come in as upper, lower or mixed case, but regardless it should be added to the proper case-insensitive header column (the header itself may be 'Region', 'REGION' etc)

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions come to mind.

1. Use `CsvBeanWriter` instead of `CsvMapWriter`, if possible.

   - or -
2. Wrap your Map with a lowercasing Map implementation (or copy the values over to a new map with the correct casing).

A lowercasing map implementation (`org.apache.commons.collections.map.CaseInsensitiveMap`) is available from [Apache Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/).

Comment: I'm not sure I can use BeanWriter in this case, as the csv is a selection of fields from about 7 different classes?

Comment: @xref You could still add a custom class that contains all values, which you add to instead of the Map.  Worst case though, reading through all the entries of your Map and putting them into a new Map with all lowercase keys would not be too difficult (not terribly efficient, but probably not a huge issue unless you are processing upwards of 100,000 rows).

Comment: Well I don't know in advance what the names of the headers will be, or how many there will be, as every csv is unique. Could a custom class handle that in supercsv?

Comment: @xref If you do not know the names of the headers then I would suggest simply remapping the values to a new map with all lowercase keys, or using a map implementation that does this automatically (E.g. `org.apache.commons.collections.map.CaseInsensitiveMap` from the Apache Commons library).